# Could not connect to SMTP GMAIL on JAVA (Connection Timeout ERROR)

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp

Hy, i have a stuck about email using SMTP java.

My configuration xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="username@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="emailService" class="com.dwidasa.iacssweb.service.feature.EmailService">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="simpleMailMessage" ref="customeMailMessage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customeMailMessage"
        class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">

        <property name="subject" value="RESET PASSWORD" />
        <property name="text">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
Dear %s,
%s
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

And the error is:

> 2019-03-20 16:11:42.151:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;|  nested exception
>   is:|?java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed
>   out). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;|  nested exception
>   is:|?java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed
>   out); message exceptions (1) are:|Failed message 1:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;|  nested exception
>   is:|?java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed
>   out)

It's happen when I move the source code to other server. When I tested in localhost, there is no error. But when I move that to server on abroad, there is error like 'Connection Timeout'..
Can someone help me to fix that ?
Please.

Comment: Port 587 is open on your server ?

Comment: Its duplicate of your same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235720/cant-send-email-overseas-via-smtp-java/55237162?noredirect=1#comment97238700_55237162